# Erro em requisição Ajax com CodeIgniter (url)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou com um problema muito estranho, caso alguém possa ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no *CodeIgniter 3.1.6* com *PHP 7.1* e *Bootstrap 4*.

- A tela inicial apresenta uma listagem de alunos (obtida de um controller chamado Aluno, método "listagem"). Nessa página eu tenho um botão para cadastro de novos alunos em um modal. Quando clico nele, o modal é exibido corretamente.
- No modal tenho um botão para salvar o novo aluno no banco MySQL, o qual faz uma requisição Ajax. O código é o seguinte:

```js
$('#btnSalvarNovoAluno').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: '<?= base_url() ?>Aluno/inserir', 
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#frmNovoAluno').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
       if(data.status)
       {
        alert('O aluno foi inserido corretamente!');
       }
      },
      error: function(){
       alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar o aluno.');
      }
     });
    });
```

No meu arquivo de configurações coloquei como "base_url":

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/sgicesecbd/';
```

Quando tento salvar, é gerado um erro porque a aplicação está tentando redirecionar para

```
http://localhost:8080/sgicesecbd/Aluno/listagem/<?=%20base_url()%20?>Aluno/inserir
```

O estranho é que se eu coloco na requisição Ajax a URL absoluta (http://localhost:8080/sgicesecbd/Aluno/inserir), funciona normalmente.

Alguém já passou por situação parecida? Agradeço desde já!

---

**Consegui resolver o problema com a ajuda do seguinte tópico:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051588/codeigniter-base-url-didnt-recongnized-in-javascript
Foi preciso criar essa variável global contendo a base_url no cabeçalho da página inicial...**

Comment: Já tentou alterar `<?= base_url() ?>` para `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` ?

Comment: Já sim, mas o problema continua o mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: Você carregou `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Sim, está carregado no construtor do controller Aluno.

Comment: Carrega ele no *Autoload* ... `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` em `application/config/autoload.php` ... Tente também dar um `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` fora do *Javascript*

Comment: Também já está sendo carregado no Autoload...

Comment: Esse código está em um arquivo js separado? Porque tudo indica que ele não está sendo processado pelo PHP. E geralmente não é o caso de processar mesmo. Sugiro que você crie uma variável JS global no head do seu HTML, e use essa variável para montar a URL da chamada ajax.

Comment: Isso aí bfavaretto, está em um arquivo JS separado mesmo. Fiz desta maneira e funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Passou de tudo pela minha cabeça, menos isso :s

Comment: Postei como resposta para ficar mais completo. Espero que ajude mais gente com o mesmo problema ou parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código JavaScript não está sendo processado pelo PHP. E isso é bom, geralmente não compensa mandar o PHP processar os JS, eles são servidos com mais eficiência se forem estáticos.

Uma solução possível é guardar esse caminho numa variável JS global, que pode ser declarada no próprio HTML:

```
...
<head>
    <script>var base_url = '<?= base_url() ?>';</script>
    <script src="seuScript.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

Com isso seu JS pode ficar assim:

```
$('#btnSalvarNovoAluno').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Aluno/inserir', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#frmNovoAluno').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status)
            {
                alert('O aluno foi inserido corretamente!');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar o aluno.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado!